# Getting Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: c#, web-services, http

I'm getting the following error when calling an non-https web service:

```
<exception>
    <type>System.IO.IOException</type>
    <message>Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.</message>
    <source>System</source>
    <stackTrace><![CDATA[   at System.Net.ConnectStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)     
    at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.WebExceptionWrapperStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)     
    at System.Net.Http.StreamToStreamCopy.BufferReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)]]></stackTrace>
    <exception>
        <type>System.Net.Sockets.SocketException</type>
        <message>An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host</message>
        <source>System</source>
        <stackTrace><![CDATA[   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginReceive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, 
        SocketFlags socketFlags, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)     
        at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.BeginRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)]]></stackTrace>
    </exception>
</exception>
```

The line of code that's throwing the error looks like:

```
        try
        {
             response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
```

The people who can read the webservice logs say that it's responding successfully.  According to my diagnostics I'm getting the error less than a second from when I send the request.  Based on what I've found on the web I've added:

```
        if (!httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Contains("Connection"))
        {
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        }
        
        if (!httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Contains("Keep-Alive"))
        {
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Keep-Alive", "3600");         
        }
```

But the Keep-Alive headers didn't help.

Thanks

Comment: I suspect you are failing because you are trying to send a non secure HTTP and server is expecting a secure HTTPS (just a guess).  The "forcibly closed" error is usually associated with a TCP connection failing which occurs during a TLS authentication.  You said "non-https web service" which I assume means that a secure connection is working.  TLS is only used for secure connections.

Comment: The same web service is successfully processing non-https calls.

Comment: Then the service (or underlying windows operating system) is rejecting the secure TLS. I'm a little confused with you comments.  In posting you said "error when calling an non-https" (where the https is secure).  Then last comment you said "successfully processing non-https calls".  So under what conditions are you passing and which conditions are you failing?

Comment: I'm making other calls like: 

`http://mydomain/mypath/48fdlsajop96f60d65f005899592b4580a5f424c659fds987sdf`

and they work.

This call to 

`http://mydomain/mypath/48fdlsajop96f60d65f005899592b4580a5f424c659fds987saa`

gives the error.

Comment: Do you have access to both folders?  Using File Explorer and see if you can get to both folders.

Comment: Which folders do you mean?  I'm retrieving large files via a web service.

Comment: The URLs in your last posting.  When was last time code ran?  Do you know the dates of the working files and non working files?  Do you know the size of working and non working files(URLs)?